# PHP - How do I include Quotes in DOM createElement?

Tags: php, xml, dom

this is throwing an error

`$exp_date = $xml->createElement("expiration_date type='datetime'");`

Is there a trick to working with quotes within quotes?

Comment: First create the element, then the attribute. It has always worked that way.

Comment: This has nothing to do with quotes. It's that `expiration_date type='datetime'` is not a valid *element*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createElemt is used in the way

```
createElement ( string $name [, string $value ] )
```

name:
The tag name of the element.

value:
The value of the element. By default, an empty element will be created.

With regards your code, you can do:

```
$exp_date = $xml->createElement("expiration_date");
$exp_date->setAttribute('type','datetime');
```

Read http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php for more info

Answer (score 6):

[`createElement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) doesn't work that way. It takes the *name* and only the name of the element as the first parameter (and the second parameter refers to the content, not the attributes). If you want to set an attribute on it, you will have to do that as a separate step:

```
$exp_date = $xml->createElement("expiration_date");
$exp_date->setAttribute('type','datetime');
```